VBA Run time error: Document Not saved [-2147024773(8007007b)]
I'm a total newbie to the programming scene and managed to do small VBA Macro to  convert XL payslips in to PDFs. I have created 03 identical VBA modules within the same work sheet to get the above done for employees from 3 different departments.
this is the message that I encounter when I try to run the 2nd and the 3rd modules;
    Document Not saved [-2147024773(8007007b)]


tried messing around with directory routes, changing directory names and etc. (Again I have no knowledge in VBA programming. I just found this code and learnt it. have a vague idea on how it works. that's pretty much it)

Please copy and paste the code into a code block within your question. If you don't know how to do a code block, just paste as normal text and someone will format it for you.

I'd take that filename and create a variable first, then its easier to check what the actual file name is, and if it looks wrong.  My guess is whatever this loop is doing is creating invalid filenames.  Microsoft doc on what isn't allowed in filenames: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file
